# Cancel Stop-Computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, shutdown

I have a program on my system called `stopwatch.exe`, so sometimes I will have
PowerShell open, and I will enter the command. However I also use tab
completion, so I will usually enter:

```
stopw TAB
```

then press enter. However if on accident I enter:

```
stop TAB
```

Then I instead get Stop-Computer, which shuts down the computer. I have done
this on accident now at least twice, and its very annoying. Does anyone has a
solution for this problem? I know with the old `shutdown.exe`, you could enter
`shutdown /a` to cancel it, but I dont know if anything like that is available
with PowerShell.

https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-computer

Comment: stupid old hack - keep an unsaved copy of notepad open and see if that stops things from rebooting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit this file:

```
C:\PowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd1
```

Just comment out this line, or remove it:

```
"Stop-Computer",
```

You wont be able to shut down with PowerShell, but I dont think I have ever
wanted or needed to do that. You can just push the power button on your computer,
or shut down from the Start Menu.

Comment: And for anyone who does not have this folder as mentioned in Steven Penny's answer (`C:\PowerShell\Modules`), you can check the paths which it may exist otherwise on your system by running `$Env:PSModulePath` in PowerShell, and then per the output from there, you will get some directory listings which to check for this file as mentioned here if you cannot find it per this advice on the location of the file to adjust.